# How can I earn trading card in Ultra Street Fighter IV?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards, ultra-street-fighter-iv

Recently I open Steam's Inventory and realize that I have 5 trading cards from Ultra Street Fighter IV (1 Decapre, 1 Elena (foil), 2 Poison, 1 Yang - I don't even play these characters much), I have no idea how & why & when did I get them.

I see that there are [10 trading cards for Ultra Street Fighter IV](https://steamtradingcards.fandom.com/wiki/Ultra_Street_Fighter_IV), how can I get them, especially the foil one? Do I need to connect to the internet while I play the game?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry to disappoint, but the [Steam Trading Cards](https://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards) do not care which characters you choose to play, but rather it gives you randomly by playing the game.

You can get half of the set by playing the game, but the other half only by buying in the Steam Market or trading.

Also, sometimes just by playing games you get a random pack for a game you have, but not exactly the game you were playing when you got it.

You don't need to play online to get the cards, but you must be online on Steam for it to see you have been playing the game.